# How to find out who modified publication properties like Publication URL etc.?

Tags: core-service, cme, database, cm-db, publication

Is there a way to find out who has modified Publication properties fields and when?

We have found that publication url was modified and pages published to wrong URL, and fixed it when we noticed. But there is no history saved for Publication or structure groups (like we have for components/schemas).

Let me know if there's a way to find it out.

Ver: 2013 SP1 HR1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Organizational Items don't have version history, Publications and Structure Groups are Organizational Items, so there is no history for them.

Understand probably it is too late, but next time you could write a simple piece of Event code to capture this

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<Publication, SaveEventArgs>(SavePublicationEventPost, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
}

private void SavePublicationEventPost(Publication publication, SaveEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)
{
    string newUrl = publication.GetPublishUrl();
    //record it
}
```

Also you can carefully design the User permissions so people who do not need to have access to that Publication don't, and/or remove "Publication Management" right from certain Users/Groups.

Comment: Do we have organizational items version history in Web 8 or 8.5 ??

Comment: @Saurabh no and it is also not on the roadmap for a future release as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

There is no 'out of the box' way to get this information, I'm afraid.

If this is a big concern then you could consider:

1. Locking-down access to the Publication Properties using security (removing `Publication Management` rights) and putting any other Publication level settings in a linked Component,
2. Implementing some custom Event System code for audit
   purposes, or
3. Creating a GUI Extension to only allow certain users or groups to be able to edit these setting in the CME.

Comment: beat me by 1 minute Jon

Comment: I'm glad to see that we gave the same answer though, Hao! :)